# How does one have custom LS_COLOR work for ZSH?

Tags: zsh, ls, colors, oh-my-zsh

I wanted to make custom colors for the `ls` command with zsh, but I find that all the previous answers to this do not work for me.

I tried all these options:

Option 1)

```
#LS_COLORS='no=00;37:fi=00:di=00;33:ln=04;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;33;01:'
#export LS_COLORS
#zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

Option 2)

```
#LS_COLORS='di=1:fi=96:*.m=31:*.py=32:*.txt=36:*.out=35'
#export LS_COLORS
#zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

Option 3)

```
#zstyle ':completiom:*' list-colors 'di=1:fi=96:*.m=31:*.py=32:*.txt=36:*.out=35'
```

Option 4)

```
#zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors 'di=34:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=46;34:cd=43;34:su=41;30:sg=46;30:tw=42;30:ow=43;30'
```

but all result of the `ls` command are displayed as if no color option was turned on.

The only thing that seems to work to change the colors at all is this:

```
unset LSCOLORS
export CLICOLOR=1
export CLICOLOR_FORCE=1
```

which I found from another answer somewhere that I can't find. However, what I want is to use my own *custom colors* indicated by:

```
#LS_COLORS='di=1:fi=96:*.m=31:*.py=32:*.txt=36:*.out=35'
```

---

Appendix

- For completness I also saw someone suggest to use `gls` but I had issues brew installing it so I gave up on that. Sorry can't find the link to that anymore.

---

Cross posted:

- reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/dvetzm/how_does_one_have_custom_ls_color_work_for_zsh/
- Quora: https://qr.ae/TWECyC

Comment: If you actually _mentioned_ that you were using MacOS, answerers would not be off on wild goose chases with the Z shell, but would no doubt be providing short and to the point explanations of why a variable named `LS_COLORS` has no effect with BSD `ls`.  They might even have pointed you in the direction of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137340/5132 where someone with a familiar name worked out the right variable names to use.  (-:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the output color of the ls command in terminal in OS X and iTerm2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137339/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-the-ls-command-in-terminal-in-os-x-and-iterm2)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing `zsh/complist` module. Try `zmodload zsh/complist`.

Besides, if you want to have the `ls` colored output – which isn't something directly related to Zsh – then you should do: `eval $(dircolors -b …path to the custom dircolors definitions…)`. Or use Zplugin and do:

```
zplugin wait"0c" lucid \
 atload'zstyle ":completion:*" list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}";' for \
    zpm-zsh/dircolors-material
```